# Why am I experiencing a daily blue screen of death with either one of these causes: DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION and HYPERVISOR_ERROR?

Tags: windows-10, freeze, bsod

I am facing a very weird issue. My desktop is an Alienware from 2014 with all the recent updates installed for Windows 10. The behavior I get is that once a day I get two blue screens:

1. `DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION`: After video froze for 1-2 minutes but audio going on.
2. `HYPERVISOR_ERROR`: Video freezes for 5-10 seconds then blue screen.

Per se these errors are nothing special, and normally I would just format my PC again since apparently some driver or program is causing me issues, however in this case I am curious.

These errors happen exactly once a day. They happen at random times, there is absolutely no pattern. They happen with any program (or none) open. Sometimes they happen 5 minutes after startup, sometimes 10 hours after.

Recently I got a blue screen at 00:15 after not getting anything for more than 12 hours (I got both blue screens the day before). This really made me curious.

From what I can tell of the past 50 days or so is that I get both blue screens, but each of them exactly once a day no matter if I restart my device or not at the daily border.

I will eventually reinstall my OS but I was wondering, does anyone have any idea how two blue screens could happen exactly once every single day.

Comment: The first is, I think, a driver error. Remove Hyper-V (Programs and Features, Windows Features), update all drivers and then restart and see if the crashing stops.

Comment: Thank you, I agree this is the way to get rid of ti, but in this case I would like to understand what exactly causes what I am observing :)

Comment: Finding why a driver crashes is like finding a needle in a haystack.   You could go for a very long time trying to find the exact cause.

Comment: You could always run Process Monitor (SysInternals) and filter for the same time of day. This will produce voluminous information. Also use Nirsoft Blue Screen View to look at dmp files for clues.